# Filter values/data in a column according to have a specific word in those data

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering

I am a beginner in R who is working on a simple file. I want to filter data and understand which rows have some values in the column "Family", which is contained "Ja" in their family name.
I am using "dplyr" package in R and prefer to do that with this package.

List 8 is my list:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3Mjw.png)

Thank you all for your support and help.

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput`? So we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Images of data can't really be used to reproduce your problem; as @Quinten suggested, use `dput` to give a sample of your data. Here is a list of other ways to post a reproducible example of your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Something like `your_data %>% filter(grepl(pattern = "Ja", Family))` should work. If you need more help, please make your example more reproducible by sharing the sample data as copy/pasteable text, not as a picture of a table. `dput(your_data[1:5, ])` is a nice way to make a copy/pasteable version of the first 5 rows of `your_data`, including all class and structure information.

Comment: Dear Friends,
Thank you all. Gregor's solution is helpful except for 1 row containing ";" in the value.
How can I fix that? imagine I have thousands of these ";" in the real world that I am not aware of where they are. How can I write a script to tackle this and cover these exceptions.
I also need to know if this script is applicable for multiple patterns in a column. I hope it will work.

Again, thank you for your time and experiences.

Answer (score 0):

In the following, I show how to return the rows of `data.frame` where a row's value for the column `Family` contains the substring "Ja".

## Manually create similar data

I'll first create similar data, adding a fake person with a family name of "jay"  to demonstrate case-sensitive filtering.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Name = c("rachel","rachal","fake","sina","Toni"),
           Family = c("Jackson","Jacki","jay", "Tobi;","Brayan"),
           Scores = rnorm(5),
           City = c("Shangha","Beijing","fake","Rome","Tokyo"))

print(df)
#>     Name  Family     Scores    City
#> 1 rachel Jackson  0.9383872 Shangha
#> 2 rachal   Jacki  0.8026869 Beijing
#> 3   fake     jay -1.4608956    fake
#> 4   sina   Tobi;  0.6325120    Rome
#> 5   Toni  Brayan -0.6269983   Tokyo
```

## Return matches (case-sensitive)

Return the rows where the Family column contains the substring "Ja". This will be case-sensitive.

```r
df %>% filter(grepl("Ja", Family))
#>     Name  Family    Scores    City
#> 1 rachel Jackson 0.9383872 Shangha
#> 2 rachal   Jacki 0.8026869 Beijing
```

## Return matches (ignores case)

What if we wanted rows regardless of the case of "Ja"?

```r
df %>% filter(grepl("Ja", Family, ignore.case = TRUE))
#>     Name  Family      Scores    City
#> 1 rachel Jackson -0.34802411 Shangha
#> 2 rachal   Jacki  0.02267559 Beijing
#> 3   fake     jay -0.74904081    fake
```

## Return row indices

What if we don't want the rows but only the row indices/numbers?

```r
grep("Ja", df$Family)
#> [1] 1 2
```

Comment: Dear @socialscientist,
I really appreciate your comprehensive answer and the different queries you suggested. All your script should work well.
 Thank you for your help. I'd like to ask my question in a different way.

Comment: I am working with genomic data. This is an example (unrealistic):

please generate this dataset for yourself:

# df <- data.frame(Gene.ref = c("SMAD11","PLEKHN1","RNF223","OR4F16","SMAD11;TP53"),
                 Chr. = c("x","y","12", "16","21"),
                 Scores = rnorm(5),
                 Variation = c("c.485C>T;NM_56731:1288G>T","c.12-2A>G","C.128del","c.15326T>C","c.113+458G>C"))


the question is: I want to extract all information and rows for those values that contain the gene list ("SMAD11", "OR4F16") in their "Gene.ref" column.

Comment: in genomic data, it is possible that you have different gene names/nomenclature for a single gene in a cell, so you should find them and avoid missing data. the same scenario is for "variation". Sometimes, I need to extract a list of 700 genes from a column. I need something like "contain" when you are writing a query in SQL server.

Thank you all for your time and your experiences.

Comment: @GeneiFit If you are asking a different question, please create a new question. If you need to modify the question for some reason, please do so and explain how this does not answer it. Please do NOT use the comments to ask a different question or rephrase your question - that is what the question itself is for. `grepl` is string matching with regular expressions, which is exactly what contains does.

Comment: I just rephrased my question. These scripts are great, however, they couldn't solve my problem. If you would like to help me, I can send you a sample file and a gene list. So, you can see why the script is not working for me. Please remember I am a beginner and the possibility of my mistake is not close to zero!
thank you

Comment: The question is what you posted initially, not a comment in response to an answer - so please update that. Please do not offer to send messages, as the purpose of this site is to provide public questions and answers that are accessible to all users. 


Here are some references on how to improve your question if you need additional help https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557


https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example